# Best way to keep an array sorted when adding/deleting cells

Tags: arrays, delphi, sorting, record, tlist

**Version of Delphi used: 2007**

Hello,

I have an array of Tecord

```
TInfo = Record
 Name : String;
 Price : Integer;
end;

var Infos : Array of Tinfo;
```

I was looking for a way to sort my `Infos` array and found what I thought to be a clever way to do it. Basically, I have a TList in which I add the pointers to each cell of the array; and then, I sort them using a custom sorting function. This TList is then used to show sorted cells in a `TListView` with `OwnerData` set to `true`.

```
var SortedInfo : TList;

...

function CompareInfo(Item1, Item2: Integer): Integer;
var
 i, j : integer;
begin
 i := Integer(Item1);
 j := Integer(Item2);
 Result := CompareText(Infos[i].Name, Infos[j].Name);
end;

...

for I := 0 to Length(Infos) - 1 do SortedInfo.Add(Pointer(I));
SortedInfo.Sort(@CompareInfo);

...

procedure InfoHandlerData(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem);
begin
 Item.Caption := Infos[Integer(SortedInfo[Item.Index])].Name;
 Item.SubItems.Add(IntToStr(Infos[Integer(SortedInfo[Item.Index])].Price);
end;
```

Now, I want to be able to add and delete cells while keeping my pointers sorted. Now, here are my problems.

1. When I add a cell, I have to resort the whole list of pointers by calling `SortedInfo.Sort(@CompareInfo);`
2. When I delete a cell, I have to clean my TList, rebuild the list of pointers and sort them again.

Now, I don't have a huge number of cells, so there is no performance problem. However, rebuilding pointers when I delete a cell and sorting **all** the pointers each time the array changes seem wrong to me. I'm sorry if my problem seems stupid, but I'm trying to learn.

Is there a right way to keep my array sorted? I'm not sure how I'm supposed to "individually" sort new cells or how I'm supposed to keep the pointers valid when a cell is deleted...

Comment: Yes, you should insert the new elements at the sorted positions instead of performing expensive sorting algorithm after each addition.

Comment: Implement a  Linked List instead of using Array or TList

Comment: @Tony That's a simply awful data structure for insertion. Giving up random access is crazy for this situation.

Comment: @David, can't see anywhere random access is required, or useful for that matter. Looks like he fell into it from vanilla pascal to me.

Comment: @tony To make insertion efficient when maintaining an order, you need random access for your binary search.

Comment: @David. Good point, being honest can't remember the last time I implemented one. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two ways to handle this, depending on usage.  But first, you should probably be using a `TList` instead of an array.  It has methods for handling insertions and deletions and keeping things in order.

If you're performing a lot of inserts at a time, you'll want to use the dirty insert algorithm, which works like this:

> The list comes with an associated flag, a boolean value called
>   `Dirty`.  When you insert something, stick it on the end of the list,
>   and set `Dirty` to `True`.  When you go to read from the list, first
>   check the `Dirty` flag, and if its value is `True`, sort the list, set
>   `Dirty := False;` and then do the read.  With a lot of inserts, this
>   is much faster than keeping the list in sorted order as you insert.

However, if you're not likely to be doing several inserts at a time, it's cheaper to maintain the list in sorted order.  You don't need to do that by calling `Sort` every time, though.  You do it like this:

> Because your data is already sorted, you can find the correct position
>   for a new value by using a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).  Have the Insert
>   operation use a binary search to determine where the new value should
>   go, insert it there, and your list remains in sorted order.

As for deletes, you shouldn't have to worry about sorting order.  Just call `Delete` on your `TList`, and if it started out sorted, removing an item won't change that.

Comment: Hmm I knew the algorithm, (Dirty Insert) never knew it had an official name though.

Comment: @Tony: I don't know if that's an official name or not. That's just what I call it. :P

Answer (score 0):

Using both a dynamic array and a TList is not good. Use one or other, but not both. Inserting is easy in TList, but you need to manage lifetime of your pointers. You are looking at heap allocation. For a dynamic array, lifetime is easy, but insertion and deletion requires a bit of care. Of course, if you had modern Delphi it would be trivial with TList.

Use insertion sort to maintain the ordering of your array. Whenever you insert a new item, insert it at a position where it is greater than the previous element, and less than the subsequent element. If your list is already ordered, then inserting following this rule maintains the ordered property. For efficiency you can use binary search to find the insertion point. For an example of this look at TStringList when Sorted is True.

Before you tackle binary search (surprisingly tricky to get right), implement a version with linear search. Prove to yourself this works, and then move on to binary search if you need the extra efficiency.

When deleting, simply delete the item. Deleting any item from an ordered array preserves the ordered property.

Your compare function is a little "odd". All you need is:

```
function CompareInfo(Item1, Item2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareText(Infos[Item1].Name, Infos[Item2].Name);
end;
```

Comment: Given it's only name and price you could cheat and do the entire thing with TStringList, or better still a class which hides it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I'll look the TStringList example. About my whole deletion problem: I delete the pointer yes, but I also delete the cell itself and I rebuild the array index (so, for instance, if I delete cell 4, cell 6 becomes cell 5...)

Comment: @AllainMcCain. Thats basically because you are using an array. If you switch to a list of some sort (no pun intended), it does that bit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to maintain a list of ordered names along with its data use TStringList instead of TList.
Use its Objects attributes to keep the record reference.

It does the sort for you whether you insert or delete items.
For example:

```
Var
   List:TStringList;
begin
   List:=TStringList.Create();
   List.Sorted:=True;
   // depending on your duplicates records use one of the following:
   List.Duplicates:=[dupIgnore, dupAccept, dupError];

   // You add record to the list this way:
   List.AddObject(RecPtr^.name, TObject(RecPtr));
   // or
   List.AddObject(MyRecord.name, TObject(@MyRecord));
   // When you want to access the record from an item, typecast it
   with TMyRecordType(List.Objects[IndexToTheObject])^ do
   begin
   end;

   // To delete an item:
   List.Delete(Index);

   // To find a specific record:
   Index:=List.IndexOf(MyNameSearch);
end;
```

Comment: Hops, Tony Hopkinson has already suggested the use of the TStringList. I did not see it. I should read all the comments carefully next time.